# Acsessing field data for a views template

Tags: entities, files

I have a client who wants to be able to input a content type which allows for the upload of 4 different pdf files. They want to have a view that allows them to click on one link and load each pdf file in a separate tab. I can get this to work in the footer of the view with the global text option and inputting the following code:

```
<a href="[field_client_first_pdf]" target="_blank"  onclick="window.open('[field_client_second_pdf]','');window.open('[field_client_third_pdf]','');">[title]</a>
```

The problem is, I need this to work in the fields using the global text option but full html is not allowed there. I am trying to use a views template file to input the code but I can not figure out how to access the data that is supplied by the replacement patterns in the view. Any tips on how I can assign variables with the right data in the template file?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Theme: Information` in the `Advanced` part of the view configuration (you need to click the `Advanced` link to expand it).

Here you can explore all the possible templates for that specific view and specific display. But additionally you can click the specific template and see the default code (in your case you will use Row template I guess). There you can see the available variables.

To print out the specific values, I would recommend [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and then the `kpr()` or `dpm()` functions, like this: `dpm($fields);` in your template.

Alternatively, you can use `debug($fields);` without using the Devel module.

*Important: Do not forget to delete these debug functions before deployment.*